# Very old 70s alien artwork book. Only remember one picture

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember seeing one book like this, it had a picture of three aliens in water with most of their heads submerged, and one was rising a little out of the water looking at the camera, they looked very creepy, it was in the art style of the Terran Trade books, but I can not find the actual book this picture is from. They had a sort of halo around their heads. The two aliens were submerged almost up to their scalps and one was risen a little out of the water. This is bothering me, I have looked at a few Terran Trade books and I can not find this picture.

Comment: Were they humanoid or something else? What color?

Comment: I think I can picture the art you're describing; it was a 1960's book cover repurposed into one of the "Stephen Caldwell" (Stewart Cowley) *Galactic Encounters* art books.

Comment: The top of the heads is sort of like the Nova Nevada Wizards, but with the rest of the body submerged, I can not tell. But it is not the wizards. It was a very, very old art book picture. Dark-colored heads.

Comment: What are the _Nova Nevada Wizards_? Google does not seem to have heard of them.

Comment: If the creatures are vaguely like the [creature from the black lagoon](https://www.google.com/search?q=creature+from+the+black+lagoon&tbm=isch) (possibly with yellow eyes?) then I think I remember the cover as well. If my memory is trustworthy the book was firmly at the pulp end of the genre.

Comment: Nova Nevada wizards are the inhabitants of Nova Nevada. They are in the Aliens In Space book. Sorry, I should have elaborated.

Comment: @John Cartwright  I expect that some peoplemght findit interersting that you describe a book from the 1970s , 44 to 54 years ago, as "very old",